# Xaml pass bound property to command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, binding

I have a `TextBox` bound to a `string` property on the `ViewModel`, and I have a `Button` with a `Command`. Now I want to pass the property itself if possible as a `CommandParameter`.
Is this possible?

Xaml part:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FilePath}" Content="..." />
```

And the `Command` looks like this, but what type do I have to put instead of the `RelayCommand<?>` and what do I need to bind the `CommandParameter` to?

```
public ICommand BrowseCommand => this.browseCommand ?? (this.browseCommand = new RelayCommand<?>(this.Browse));
```

Comment: Filepath is of type string I assume?

Comment: yes it is, and I wanted to pass the property itself, not its value (if that is possible)

Comment: That's not possible. {Binding} resolves the *value*.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want a reference to the property? Maybe there  is another way. Describe your situation.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. So I have multiple `TextBox`es and each is bound to its own property. For each `TextBox` i have a `Button` which should set the property of the appropiate `TextBox`. I wanted to use a single command for all `Button`s and the only way I could think of is that the `Command` needs to know the property it should set. I hope it gets clear :#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you are using the `RelayCommand<T>` class from MvvmLight:

```
public ICommand BrowseCommand => this.browseCommand ?? (this.browseCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(this.Browse));

private void Browse(string obj)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that too and it works, but `obj` holds the value of the property, not the property itself. I was looking for a way so that inside of `Browse` I could use `obj` as the property it is (e.g. setting `obj` would show on the UI

Comment: That's not supported. You will get the *value* of the property passed as a command parameter.

Comment: so there is no way to pass the actual property? okay, thank you for your answer